# Partial batch sizes

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to simulate pallet behavior by using batch and move to. This works fine except towards the end where the number of elements left is smaller than the batch size, and these never get picked up. Any way out of this situation?

Have tried messing with custom queues, pickup/dropoff pairs.

To elaborate, the batch object has a queue size of 15. However once the entire set has been processed a number of elements less than 15 remain which don't get picked up by the subsequent moveTo block. I need to send the agents to the subsequent block once the queue size falls below 15.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the batch size of your Batch object towards "the end" (whatever you mean by that :-) ). You need to figure out *when* to change the batch size (as this depends on your model). But once it is time to adjust, you can call `myBatchItem.set_batchSize(1)` and it will now batch things together individually.

However, a better *model design* might be to have a cool-down period before the model end, i.e. stop taking model measurements before your batch objects run out of agents to batch.

Comment: The model is a warehouse of sorts where cartons get processed in batches of 15. However once we run out of cartons, the remaining cartons also need to be processed as a batch even if the size is less than 15. That is the "end".

Comment: well, use Felipe's approach above. Determine after each batching if there will be more than 15 cartons to batch again. If not, dynamically reduce the batch size as stated, to the number of remaining cartons. Or better, set the batch size dynamically always: if you have 15 or more cartons: 15. Else: whatever you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what the last element is somehow for example using a boolean variable called `isLast` in your agent that is true for the last agent.

and in the batch you have to change the batch size programatically.. maybe like this in the on enter action of your batch:

```
if(agent.isLast) 
    self.set_batchSize(self.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the "end" or any lack of supply is reached, I suggest a timeout. I would save a timestamp in a variable `lastBatchDate` in the OnExit code of the batch block:

```java
lastBatchDate = date();
```

A cyclically activated event `checkForLeftovers` will check every once in a while if there is objects waiting to be batched and the timeout (here: 10 minutes) is reached. In this case, the batch size will be reduced to exactly the number of waiting objects, in order for them to continue in a smaller batch:

```java
if( lastBatchDate!=null //prevent a NullPointerError when date is not yet filled
    && ((date().getTime()-lastBatchDate.getTime())/1000)>600 //more than 600 seconds since last batch
    && batch.size()>0 //something is waiting
    && batch.size()<BATCH_SIZE //not more then a normal batch is waiting
){
    batch.set_batchSize(batch.size()); // set the batch size to exactly the amount waiting
}
else{
    batch.set_batchSize(BATCH_SIZE); // reset the batch size to the default value BATCH_SIZE
}
```

The model will look something like this:

[image: Batch Model]

However, as Benjamin already noted, you should be careful if this is what you really need to model. Take care for example on these aspects:

- Is the timeout long enough to not accidentally push smaller batches during normal operations?
- Is the timeout short enough to have any effect?
- Is it ok to have a batch of a smaller size downstream in your process?
- etc.

You might just want to make sure upstream that the number of objects reaches the batching station are always filling full batches, or you might to just stop your simulation before the line "runs dry".

You can see the model and download the source code [here](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/9dcf684a-d402-4ce4-85d2-57c63410528e?mode=SETTINGS).